# swift iOS Bluetooth: Does a delegate method always get called?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

Am new to Swift and iOS Bluetooth - coming from Android. There are several methods on the CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral objects where the documentation states that a delegate method is called.

The question I have is simple - will the delegate method ALWAYs be called or are there situations where some error condition happens such that the delegate method is not called? In other words, after invoking the call, do I need to invoke some kind of wait on a semaphore and perhaps have a timeout?

For example, the CBPeripheral.discoverServices has a delegate method CBPeripheral: didDiscoverServices. Will that delegate ALWAYs get signaled?

Comment: It will get called as long as the peripheral has services. In some cases the delegate receives an error parameter.  You should never `wait`; the delegate call backs are asynchronous. If you want to use a `Timer` to provide some sort of time out functionality you can.

Comment: I understand they are asynchronous. I tried waiting on a semaphore, making the call, invoking the wait, and releasing the wait in the delegate callback. When I did that, the delegate callback never got called. When I removed the semaphore, it did get called.

Comment: Yes, because you blocked the thread that is needed to call the delegate. There is no need to block.  Don't try and make asynchronous events synchronous.

Comment: In Android the calls themselves are asynchronous. So the call to do service discovery returns immediately. In that case I do wait on a semaphore for the callback. Then I do the next thing. Clearly the call spawns its own thread and I kind of assumed it was the same here.

Comment: Turning asynchronous calls into synchronous calls (which you are doing with a semaphore) is the wrong approach.

Comment: Not on Android! If you don't block before the next call to a write characteristic oe any other BLE action that invokes a callback, you will lose it! (Of course if one could something else then one could, but in my case all I need to do is more BLE actions so I have to make sure the first one is done.) If I make a call in the callback, it will block the receive thread. On iOS it appears to be the complete opposite. I dont understand what iOS is doing that my wait would block them - I can understand blocking the receive thread - that is a common problem on embedded systems.

Comment: I don't know about Android, but Core Bluetooth works correctly. You can have a failed write if you fill the queue by sending too much data too quickly but the correct implementation is to detect the failed write,  wait for the callback indicating that space is available and retry the write.

Comment: In any case, the call is clearly not asynchronous. If it were, I should be able to do whatever I want after making the call. That's the idea of asynchronous.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Asynchronous doesn't mean stateless.  Core Bluetooth is asynchronous in that you send requests, the call doesn't block and  they will compete some unspecified time later.  Your code needs to wait for the notification that the task has completed before it can rely on the state.  A semaphore is one way of waiting for that state but is generally not the best.  After making a Core Bluetooth call you can then do whatever you want as long as it doesn't rely on the data from that call.

Comment: For example, you can call discoverServices and then update your UI to reflect you have initiated service discovery and then do nothing until you get the delegate callback.

Comment: That's what I WAS using the semaphone for. I made the asynchronous call and did not want to take the next step until the callback was signaled. I don't understand why the wait on the semaphore caused the callback not to get called. So now I make the 'async' call and return. When the callback get signaled, I make the next call in that callback ... something I would never do on an embedded system!

Comment: Right, but this isn't an embedded system.  Embedded systems typically don't have a multi-tasking os (I know they can); you are responsible for that yourself and you are in control.  you don't typically have to worry about impacts on what else the system may be doing. Mobile operating systems are very different. They are user focussed and user controlled.  The user expects to be able to interact with your app and their device at any time.  The system has lots of other things it can be doing while your code is waiting for some async event.